# Floated right DIV appears below the others appears below in shadowbox Chrome only

Tags: html, google-chrome, css-float

I have been trying to get a long list into three columns without using a table. This list is displayed by popping up in a shadow box. However the third DIV (the float right DIV) appears below the other two in Chrome but not in Safari, FF or IE. Is there any explanation / fix for this?

[image: Example]

Here is some code:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 30%; position: relative;display: block;">

<P class="list">Aareon</p>
<P class="list">ABC Systems and Development</p>
...ect
</div>


<div style="float: left; width: 30%; position: relative; display: inline-block;">

<P class="list">EDS</p>
<P class="list">Electoral Office</p>
...ect
</div>

<div style="float: right; width: 30%;  position: relative; display: inline-block;">
<P class="list">Pfizer Adams</p>
<P class="list">Philips Electronics</p>
...ect
</div>
```

CSS

```
P.list {margin:5px 0px; line-height:16px;padding-left:10px;text-indent:-7px}
P.list:before {content:url('../images/bullet.png');position:relative;left:-3px
}
```

*I have tried it without the inline-blocks, position: relative, and increasing the shadow box pop-up size. 
*The code for the shadowbox is fine as it works with other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each floated DIV should share the `100%` width, if you want to place all the DIVs in a row.
In this case, you are assigning `30%` to each DIV and added `padding-left:10px` for each P tag, so your width becomes

```
DIV width = 30% + 10px
```

So first inspect the width of each DIV and try to adjust the `width (%)` or try to reduce the padding left value.
Display property value is not required, if you use `FLOAT`.

EDIT: Also reset the html tags by using CSS reset classes to overcome unnecessary margin and padding on each html tag.

Comment: I knew it would be something like that, that's why it was at 30% not 33%, when I went down to 28% it all worked fine, CSS reset is a good call i'll try it out. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have widths in percentages and have padding and margins in `px`. The widths which are in percentage are calculated by the browser later onload. As all browsers have different viewport widths, that is why the result is change. You should also use margins and paddings in percentages.

Answer (score 0):

The padding is throwing the total width off. You can fix this using these two tips:

One of your divs does not need the float, because the other ones float to the left or right of something else. It doesn't matter which it is, but try just having the left div without float and the other two float:right, and make sure the HTML for the right two divs is before the left div.

To make the sizing easier, you could have one div set to width:auto so that it uses the available width that the other divs leave